# JTextArea doesn't set the text indicator on the right before start typing

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

The only issue I'm having here is that the text indicator is always displayed on the left side until I start typing.

Before typing:

[image]

After typing:

[image]

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
textArea.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);
scroll.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```

Here is the full code:

```
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Test extends JFrame {
    
    public Test() {
        this.setSize(300, 100);
        
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scroll.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        
        scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        this.add(scroll);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

I'm using Java 11 on Windows 10 by the way.

Comment: I experimented with your code.  Every time I paused my typing, the cursor jumped to the leftmost position on the line.  When I resumed typing, the cursor returned to the right.  Spaces didn't show on the GUI until I typed a non-space character.  The setCaretPosition method doesn't function until you have at least one character in the underlying Document.  Interesting.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 10; Java 14.0.2 compiled to the Java 8 standard.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do the trick for me (tested on windows).

```
textArea.append("1");
textArea.setText("");
```

It's a little hacky but it is as you say. Without writing anything the caret is per default to the left.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It will work even if one adds it before `setVisible(true)`.

Comment: This hack only works when the JTextArea is empty.  Type a sentence, ending the sentence with a period.  Notice where the cursor and the period are displayed in the JTextArea.